# Changing M4a sampling rate to a customized value

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to change the sampling rate of an M4a file from 44100Hz to a customized value let's say 51200Hz. I used the followng command which worked fine with wav sampling rate conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -ar 51200 audio_51200.m4a
```

Unfortunately, it generates a file with a 48000 Hz sampling rate. Any ideas?

Comment: AAC encoders in ffmpeg only support the preset rates mentioned in the ISO 14496-3 standard.

Comment: Thanks for your response! do you have any reference stats that?

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -h encoder=aac` for the native encoder supported rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limited set of frequencies for AAC profiles. For example for HE AAC:

[image]
http://www.atsc.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/A153-Part-8-2012.pdf

So `ffmpeg` adjust any non-standard frequency to nearest available

**Update**: The set of available sampling frequencies is limited by AAC ADIF (Audio Data Interchange Format) and ADTS (Audio Data Transport Stream). So other rates just can't be encoded. Here are values for field `sampling_frequency_index` form subclause `8.1.1.2` in [ISO/IEC 13818-7](https://www.iso.org/standard/43345.html) standard:
[image: Sampling frequency encoding]

Recommendations for selecting sample frequency:

[image: Sampling frequency mapping]

Comment: Great. This is the standard sampling frequencies for AAC encoding but this doesn't explicitly state that I can't use non-standard sampling rates. I need to get to any reference or documentation saying so. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ISO/IEC 14496-3 actually specifies the *possibility* of other sampling frequencies, but does not explain how to actually deduce the changed coefficients (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58931138/435093). Also ADIF is not the only format (e.g. ADTS)

Comment: @slhck `.m4a` must meet requirements of `ISO/IEC 13818-7` and it allow only frequencies given in my answer. 

`sampling_frequency_index` apply to ADTS too as it is part of `adts_fixed_header`.