# Can non-standard sampling rates be used with AAC encoding?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, aac, m4a

I am trying to up-sampling an M4a file from 41000 to another non-standard sampling rate let's say 5000.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -ar 5000 audio_.wav
```

This worked fine with wav files whoever it didn't work with m4a. Any ideas why?

If non-standard sampling rates don't work with AAC I need any documentation or reference for that.

Comment: The standard itself does not limit sampling rates but the payload has to be generated by some encoder and has to be accepted by some decoder. If you're asking for documentation that no encoder and decoder exists for non-standard rates, I think you'll be disappointed. FFmpeg's encoders and decoders only supported the enumerated frequencies.

Comment: Eh, I guess you just got [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911344/changing-m4a-sampling-rate-to-a-customized-value) from someone else. Please don't post duplicate questions…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing M4a sampling rate to a customized value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911344/changing-m4a-sampling-rate-to-a-customized-value)

Answer (score 4):

The set of available sampling frequencies is limited by AAC ADIF (Audio Data Interchange Format) and ADTS (Audio Data Transport Stream). So other rates just can't be encoded in AAC stream. Here are values for field `sampling_frequency_index` form `8.1.1.2` in [ISO/IEC 13818-7](https://www.iso.org/standard/43345.html) standard:
[image: Sampling frequency encoding]

*About @slhck answer*

According to ISO/IEC 13818-7 paragraph 8.2.3:

> **8.2.3 Decoding Process**
>
> Assuming that the start of a raw_data_block() is known, it can be decoded without any additional „transport-level“ information and produces 1024 audio samples per output channel. The sampling rate of the audio signal, as specified by the **sampling_frequency_index**, may be specified in a program_config_element() or it may be implied in the specific application domain. In the latter case, the **sampling_frequency_index** must be deduced in order for the bitstream to be parsed.
>
> Since a given sampling frequency is associated with only one sampling frequency table, and since maximum flexibility is desired in the range of possible sampling frequencies, the following Table shall be used to associate an implied sampling frequency with the desired sampling frequency dependent tables.
>   [image: Sampling frequency mapping]

This table is for sampling_frequency_index deduction. And standards (both ISO/IEC 13818-7 and ISO/IEC 14496-3) imply that encoding have been made with one of these fixed frequencies.

Comment: Good info, but there is no point posting the same answer again – I've marked the question to be closed as a duplicate, since you already answered the OP's previous question.

Comment: @slhck question is duplicate, agree